# Is there a way to make this code for the Lunchbox problem more efficient and more readable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization

I'm trying to solve a problem where there are **n** number of lunch boxes and **m** number of schools. And I'm trying to figure out the maximum amount of school that i could give lunch boxes to.

- the first line of input is the number of lunchboxes and schools there are
- and the next input is the number of lunch boxes that a school is required (I either could give no lunch boxes or either give them the exact amount they ask)

Example input:
10 4
3
9
4
2

Example output:
3

This is the code that I'm using

```
#import Library
from itertools import combinations

#Variables
Lunchbox_List = []
Result_List = []

#Insert number of Lunchbox and School
Lunchbox, Schools = map(int, input().split())
#Insert the number of Lunchbox that each school request
for i in range (1, Schools+1):
    Lunchbox_List.append(int(input()))
#Count the maximum ammount of school
for j in range (1, len(Lunchbox_List)+1):
    for k in combinations(Lunchbox_List, j):
        if sum(k) <= Lunchbox:
            Result_List.append(k)
print(len(max(Result_List, key=len)))
```

It works but it's slow and kinda hard to read. Is there a way to fix it? I'm new to python.

Comment: What do you want to fix: slowness, or readableness? By the way, I don't find it all too hard to read.

Comment: Well the main problem is the speed so slowness

Answer (score 2):

If you sort the array first you just have to go through the first schools until you don't have enough lunch boxes. This way you don't have to iterate through the whole list of schools.

Edit:
The solution I am talking about

```
#Variables
Lunchbox_List = []
Result_Count = 0

#Insert number of Lunchbox and School
Lunchbox, Schools = map(int, input().split())

#Insert the number of Lunchbox that each school request
for i in range (0, Schools):
    Lunchbox_List.append(int(input()))
    
Lunchbox_List.sort()
for j in range (0, Schools):
    if Lunchbox > Lunchbox_List[j]:
        Lunchbox -= Lunchbox_List[j]
        Result_Count += 1
    else:
        break

print (Result_Count)
```

Comment: Can you give me an example of that?

Comment: The version I proposed sort the needs of each schools by ascending orders. This way you give lunch boxes to schools that needs the least of them first, thus maximizing the number of schools you can satisfy.